# Xml Serialization of a custom XSD type

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

I have a C# class member like so:

```
class Case
{
  string ID;
  string JurisdictionID;
}
```

the corresponding XSD looks like:

```
<xs:element name="CaseTrackingID" type="IDType"/>

<xs:complexType name="IDType">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="IDJurisdictionText" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element name="IDType" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

How would I annotate my class so that `CaseTrackingID\ID` maps to `Case.ID` and `CaseTrackingID\IDJurisdictionText` maps to `Case.JurisdictionID`?

Comment: 'xsd.exe /c myschema.xsd' will generate a marked up class you can use as the basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the schema and class structures don't quite line up you have a couple of options, none of them that pretty..

```
public class Case
{
    [XmlIgnore] public string ID;
    [XmlIgnore] public string JuristictionID;

    [XmlElement("CaseTrackingID")]
    public CaseTrackingID SerializedCaseTrackingID
    {
      get 
      { 
          return new CaseTrackingID 
          { 
              ID = this.ID, 
              JuristictionID = this.JuristictionID,
          }; 
      }
      set 
      { 
          this.ID = value.ID; 
          this.JuristictionID = value.JuristictionID;
      }
    }
}
public class CaseTrackingID 
{
    [XmlElement("ID")]
    public string ID;

    [XmlElement("IDJurisdictionText")]
    public string JurisdictionID;
}
```

Or, if you're using DCSerializer, you can use the surrogate feature (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733064.aspx) to substitute a different class structure at serialization time.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
[XmlRoot("CaseTrackingID")]
public class Case
{
    [XmlElement("ID")]
    public string ID;

    [XmlElement("IDJurisdictionText")]
    public string JurisdictionID;
}
```

Comment: The `<CaseTrackingID>` element is actually a child of a `<Case>` element so I can't annotate my `Case` class as suggested.

Comment: @Jeff Swensen, And how `CaseTrackingID` is represented in your class?

Comment: CaseTrackingID isn't represented.  I'm trying to apply the Serialization annotations to a code-first EF class which matches the database tables.

Comment: @Jeff Swensen, According to provided schema your XML should looks like: `<CaseTrackingID>
    <ID></ID>
    <IDJurisdictionText></IDJurisdictionText>
    <IDType></IDType>
</CaseTrackingID>`. Where is `Case` element?

Comment: @Jeff Swensen, Provide part of schema with `Case` element.